# ZonedDateTime serialize epoch milliseconds with FasterXML Jackson

Tags: java, java-8, jackson, fasterxml, zoneddatetime

I'm intended to use *epoch millisecond* for the deserialization and serialization.
However only the deserialzation works but **failed to serialize** back to the correct `ZonedDateTime`.

```js
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, false);

System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(ZonedDateTime.now()));  // print 1493703996728 [Expected]
System.out.println(mapper.readValue("1493703996728", ZonedDateTime.class)); // print +49303-08-07T00:52:08+08:00[Asia/Singapore] [Unexpected]
```

how to make the serialize to get the date of `2017-05-02T13:46:36.728+08:00[Asia/Singapore]`?

*version of com.fasterxml.jackson.* are all 2.8.8*

Comment: It seems you desrialization understands 1493703996728 as seconds since the epoch, not milliseoncds. Don’t know how that can be.

Comment: yes indeed, it will parse correctly if it is `1493703996.728`, but this is not what i want :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You also need to disable nanoseconds for deserialization to make Jackson parse milliseconds:

```
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, false);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Manos! i'm keep looking at the options inside `SerializationFeature` enum, but totally overlooked of `DeserializationFeature`